# Android cursor out of bounds exception

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Error is  cursor index out of bounds exception, cursor is empty, receiving nothing.

**Here is logcat:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main: com.example.root.notebook, PID:
    .database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:460)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
    at com.example.root.notebook.NotebookDbAdapter.cursorToNote(NotebookDbAdapter.java:101)
    at com.example.root.notebook.NotebookDbAdapter.createNote(NotebookDbAdapter.java:67)
    at com.example.root.notebook.NoteEditFragment$4.onClick(NoteEditFragment.java:160)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:163)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**NotebookDbAdapter.java**

```
 package com.example.root.notebook;

    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.util.Log;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Calendar;

    /**
     * Created by root on 28/04/2016.
     */
    public class NotebookDbAdapter {

        private static final String DATABASE_NAME="notebook.db";
        private static final int  DATABASE_VERSION=1;
        public static final String NOTE_TABLE="note";
        public static final String COLUMN_ID="_id";
        public static final String COLUMN_TITLE="title";
        public static final String COLUMN_MESSAGE="message";
        public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY="category";
        public static final String COLUMN_DATE="date";

        public String[] allColumns={COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_TITLE, COLUMN_MESSAGE, COLUMN_CATEGORY, COLUMN_DATE};

        public static final String CREATE_TABLE_NOTE= " create table " + NOTE_TABLE + " ( "
                + COLUMN_ID +" integer primary key autoincrement, "
                +COLUMN_TITLE +" text not null, "
                +COLUMN_MESSAGE+ " text not null, "
                +COLUMN_CATEGORY+" integer not null, "
                +COLUMN_DATE+" ); ";
        private SQLiteDatabase sqlDB;
        private NotebookDbHelper notebookDbHelper;
        private Context context;
        public NotebookDbAdapter (Context ctx){
            context=ctx;
        }

        public NotebookDbAdapter open() throws android.database.SQLException{

            notebookDbHelper=new NotebookDbHelper(context);
            sqlDB=notebookDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

            return this;

        }
        public void close(){

            notebookDbHelper.close();
        }

        public Note createNote(String title,String message,Note.Category category){

            ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
            values.put(COLUMN_TITLE,title);
            values.put(COLUMN_MESSAGE,message);
            values.put(COLUMN_CATEGORY,category.name());
            values.put(COLUMN_DATE, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + "");

            long insertId=sqlDB.insert(NOTE_TABLE,null,values);

            Cursor cursor=sqlDB.query(NOTE_TABLE,allColumns, COLUMN_ID  + " = " + insertId , null, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            Note newNote=cursorToNote(cursor);
            cursor.close();
            return  newNote;

        }


        public long deleteNote(long idToDelete){
            return sqlDB.delete(NOTE_TABLE,COLUMN_ID +" = "+idToDelete ,null);
        }
        public long updateNote(long idToUpdate,String newTitle,String newMessage,Note.Category newCategory){
            ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
            values.put(COLUMN_TITLE,newTitle);
            values.put(COLUMN_MESSAGE,newMessage);
            values.put(COLUMN_CATEGORY,newCategory.name());
            values.put(COLUMN_DATE, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + "");

            return sqlDB.update(NOTE_TABLE, values ,COLUMN_ID + " = " + idToUpdate, null);

        }


        public ArrayList<Note> getAllnotes(){
            ArrayList<Note> notes=new ArrayList<Note>();
            Cursor cursor=sqlDB.query(NOTE_TABLE,allColumns, null ,null ,null ,null ,null);
            for (cursor.moveToLast();  !cursor.isBeforeFirst();  cursor.moveToPrevious()){
                Note note=cursorToNote(cursor);
                notes.add(note);
            }
            cursor.close();
            return notes;

        }
        private Note cursorToNote(Cursor cursor){
            Note newNote=new Note(cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2), Note.Category.valueOf(cursor.getString(3)),
                    cursor.getLong(0),cursor.getLong(4));
            return newNote;

        }
    private static class NotebookDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


        NotebookDbHelper(Context ctx){
            super(ctx,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_NOTE);
        }
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db,int oldVersion,int newVersion){

            Log.w(NotebookDbHelper.class.getName(),"upgrading database from version "+ newVersion+"to"+oldVersion+",which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("Drop table if exist "+ NOTE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);

        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: because query returns zero result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your below code

```
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Note newNote=cursorToNote(cursor);
        cursor.close();
        return  newNote;
```

With

```
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            Note newNote=cursorToNote(cursor);
            cursor.close();
            return  newNote;
    } 
    else {
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: thanks you bro..    can you explain why this happen?what was mistake ?

Comment: @MohammadAmir please accept the answer. Welcome :-)

Comment: @MohammadAmir if no record is available that satisfy your sql query, then cursor is null and you was calling cursor.moveToFirst() on null so exception is raised. So always check cursor if not null or empty before using it.

Comment: plz bro see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346155/edit-sqlite-query?noredirect=1#comment62209438_37346155

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  public ArrayList<Note> getAllnotes(){
        ArrayList<Note> notes=new ArrayList<Note>();
        Cursor cursor = sqlDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + NOTE_TABLE, null);
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Note note=new Note(cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2), Note.Category.valueOf(cursor.getString(3)), cursor.getLong(0),cursor.getLong(4));
                    notes.add(note);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }

        cursor.close();
        return notes;
    }
```

Comment: not working yet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346155/edit-sqlite-query?noredirect=1#comment62209438_37346155